# Инжект кода в процесс

Tags: winapi, процесс, c++

Приветствую All!
Пытаюсь внедрить функцию в чужой процесс:

```
DWORD PIDByName(char * AProcessName)
{
  HANDLE pHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  PROCESSENTRY32 ProcessEntry;
  DWORD pid;
  ProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof(ProcessEntry);
  bool Loop = Process32First(pHandle, &ProcessEntry);

  while (Loop)
    {
      if (strstr(ProcessEntry.szExeFile, AProcessName))
      {
          pid = ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID;
          CloseHandle(pHandle);
          return pid;
      }
      Loop = Process32Next(pHandle, &ProcessEntry);
    }
    return 0;
}
..
void EnableDebugPrivilege(bool fEnable)
{
    HANDLE hToken;

    if(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
    {
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid);
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = fEnable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;
        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
}

int func()//Функция для внедрения
{
HANDLE han;
char path1[] = "c:\\1.exe";
han = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);
ShellExecute (han, NULL, path1, NULL, NULL, 0x09);
}

.....
int main()
{
HANDLE handle;
DWORD pid;
int i;

EnableDebugPrivilege(True);
pid = PIDByName("spider.exe");

handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

lpMemory = VirtualAllocEx(handle, NULL, как определить размер функции?, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

WriteProcessMemory(handle, (void*)lpMemory, ?, размер функции?, NULL);

system("pause");
}
```

Как осуществить запись моей функции в память процесса и выполнить её?
Интересует именно запись кода, а не dll.

Comment: @Alexey68, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Windows.h>

wchar_t * _exe_name = L"target.exe";

DWORD WINAPI inject(LPVOID)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "", "", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    DWORD pid = 0;  
    DWORD id;
    DWORD ByteOfWriten;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DWORD size=((PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)((LPVOID)((BYTE*)(hModule)+((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(hModule))->e_lfanew+sizeof(DWORD)+sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER))))->SizeOfImage;

    if(CreateProcess(_exe_name, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        pid = pi.dwProcessId;

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
    if(process==NULL) return 0;

    LPVOID alloc = (char*)VirtualAllocEx(process,hModule,size,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if(alloc==NULL) return 0;

    BOOL w = WriteProcessMemory(process,alloc,hModule,size,&ByteOfWriten);
    if(w==NULL) return 0;

    HANDLE thread=CreateRemoteThread(process,0,0,inject,(LPVOID)alloc,0,&id);
    if(thread==NULL) return 0;

    CloseHandle(process);
    return 0;
}
```